# How to design a database service class

Tags: postgresql, go

I want to create a class that takes a sql connection, and then I can write methods to return data from my database.

```
func main() {
  db := dbConnect()
  defer db.Close()

  // pass the db to my dbservice.go somehow?
}
```

Then in my handlers (for a web app) I want to be able to do:

```
var userKey, err := dbService.getUserKey(123)
```

Do I just create a file like dbservice.go  and then create structs that represent my return values, and then do:

```
func (mystruct *MyStruct) GetUserKey(id int64) (key string, err error) {
   //
}
```

Also, how do I pass the db to this in my main so it can use the database connection?

Comment: What if db is global variable and you initialize in main the way you have now. But instead of ":=" , you could use "="

Answer (score 0):

Have the service have an internal field that takes a pointer to the db and use that.

```
type DBService struct {
    db *sql.DB
}

func (dbs *DBService) GetUserKey(id int64) (key string, err error)
    dbs.db.Query("SOMETHING")
    return
}

func NewService(db *sql.DB) *DBService { return &DBService{db: db} }
```

Comment: Also read: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/interface-with-your-database-in-go + http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/organising-database-access#using-an-interface + https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/structuring-applications-in-go-3b04be4ff091#.gfybgb2n4